# How to append a file through ssh?

Tags: ssh

I want to append a file that is already present on the server through ssh
i m try:

```
  ssh root@192.168.100.195 echo "hello gourav how are you">/g.txt
```

[image]

but no data in g.txt

Comment: Do you want to append to a file, or do you want to append the file with the name `hello pourav how are you` to the file `g.txt`. Your question title suggests that you want to append an file to some other file, your code suggests another. Please update your question to make the title match your problem unambiguously.

Comment: don't post screenshots when text will do.  just cut and paste the text from the terminal.   screenshots are a) non-searchable, b) unreadable on monitors with higher/different resolution to yours.

Comment: btw, your command will write the output of your ssh command to `/g.txt` on the **local** system.  try `ssh root@192.168.100.195 'echo "hello gourav how are you" > /g.txt'` - note that the entire command (including the redirection) to be executed by the remote host via ssh is enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add single-quotes around the remote command:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.100.195 'echo "hello gourav how are you" >> /g.txt'
```

*EDIT: yes, as @Andrew Miloradovsky noted, use `>>` rather than `>` for appending rather than writing anew.*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
$ ssh user@host "cat remote-file-1 >> remote-file-2"
```

assuming the files are at `user`'s home